# Google Sites checkbox value in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

On Google sites on edit mode, I have prepared a checkbox using Insert - HTML Box

and within the HTML Box the following code..

```
<style>
  div{
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function putResult(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AkkxdNrvyzqzdE1yU21FRGJ6akJ6MmZiSVhTN0JMNnc");
  var calc = ss.getSheetByName("Customer");

  var chvalue = e.parameter.bike
  calc.getRange("C3").setValue("chvalue");
}
</script>



<div>
  EDC:
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" onclick="putResult(e)">
</div>
```

Now my requirements:

1. I want simply a True/False based on checkbox to be populated in the SS.Calc (C3) Sheet.
2. The page should automatically be refreshed each time the checkbox is clicked.

I am a novice and in learning stage. Please do shout if things are unclear.

PS:

- I copied some code within GAS, that's where the `e.parameter.bike` comes from, don't know if that's the right way...
- I have also inserted a chart in the Google sites with source data from spreadsheet (insert Chart), I want to make it dynamic using checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Old but, since April 2018 they implemented a checkbox in spreadsheets.

You can find it in `Menu > insert > checkbox` or if you add a datavalidation.

Dealing with your Task by simply checking the field value with

```
=IF(A1=TRUE();"Checked";"Unchecked")
```

should be way more easy now! It also instantly checks state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML Box is not accepting onclick , not sure but by inspecting the checkbox in firebug you can see that there is no onclick for the element.
I think you can do it using google app script as follows,
In code.gs file,

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

and have file called Test.html.This can be created File --> New --> Script File, in that have the following code,

```
 <style>
  div{
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function putResult() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AkkxdNrvyzqzdE1yU21FRGJ6akJ6MmZiSVhTN0JMNnc");
  var calc = ss.getSheetByName("Customer");

  var chvalue = document.getElementById('bike').value;
  calc.getRange("C3").setValue("chvalue");
}
</script>



<div>
  EDC:
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" onclick="putResult()">
</div>
```

I haven't tested the above code.Try this if it works for you.